# Unix bash scripting sort

Tags: bash, unix

i need help to calculate and display the largest and average of a group of input numbers.

The program should accept a group of numbers, each can be up to 3 digits.

For example, input of 246, 321, 16, 10, 12345, 4, 274 and 0 should result in 321 as the largest and the average of 145, with an error message indicating that 12345 is invalid.

Any ideas how to sort in bash ? Sorry I am not developer in this low level, any help is great :)

Comment: There is the `sort` command. `man sort`

Answer (score 1):

I see that you ask for a `Bash` solution but since you tagged it also `Unix` I suggest a pure `awk` solution (`awk` is just ideal for such problems):

```
awk '
  {
    if(length($1) <= 3 && $1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/) {
      if($1 > MAX) {MAX = $1}
      SUM+=$1
      N++
      print $1, N, SUM
    } else {
      print "Illegal Input " $1
    }
  }
  END {
    print "Average: " SUM / N
    print "Max: " MAX
  }
' < <(echo -e "246\n321\n16\n10\n12345\n4\n274\n0")
```

prints

```
246 1 246
321 2 567
16 3 583
10 4 593
Illegal Input 12345
4 5 597
274 6 871
0 7 871
Average: 124.429
Max: 321
```

However, I cannot comprehend why the above input yields 145 as average?

Answer (score 0):

```
tmpfile=`mktemp`
while read line ; do
  if [[ $line =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}$ ]] ; then 
    # valid input
    if [ $line == "0" ] ; then
      break
    fi  
    echo $line >> $tmpfile
  else 
    echo "ERROR: invalid input '$line'"
  fi  
done
awk ' { tot += $1; if (max < $1) max = $1; } \
  END { print tot / NR; print max; } ' $tmpfile
rm $tmpfile
```

Answer (score 0):

A piped `coreutils` option with `bc`:

```
echo 246 321 16 10 12345 4 274 0           \
| grep -o '\b[0-9]{1,3}\b'                 \
| tee >(sort -n | tail -n1 > /tmp/max)     \
| tr '\n' ' '                              \
| tee >(sed 's/ $//; s/ \+/+/g' > /tmp/add) \
      >(wc -w > /tmp/len) > /dev/null

printf "Max: %d, Min: %.2f\n" \
  $(< /tmp/max)               \
  $((echo -n '('; cat /tmp/add; echo -n ')/'; cat /tmp/len) | bc -l)
```

Output:

```
Max: 321, Min: 124.43
```

- `grep` ensures that the number format constraint.
- `sort` finds max, as suggested by *chepner*
- `sed` and `wc` generate the sum and divisor.

Note that this generates 3 temporary files: `/tmp/{max,add,len}`, so you might want to use `mktemp` and/or deletion:

```
rm /tmp/{max,add,len}
```

#### Edit

Stick this into the front of the pipe if you want to know about invalid input:

```
tee >(tr ' ' '\n'            \
      | grep -v '\b.{1,3}\b' \
      | sed 's/^/Invalid input: /' > /tmp/err)
```

And do `cat /tmp/err` after the `printf`.